# Google sheets COUNTIF excluding hidden rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, countif, sumproduct

In google sheets, I have a list of strings (1 per row) where each string is split with 1 character per column, so my sheet looks something like below:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | F | R | A | N | K |  |
| **2** | P | A | S | S | 1 | 2 |

I then have this sheet filtered, so Can select only the rows where the first character is F, for example. On another sheet in the same workbook, I have a table of how often each character appears in each column, that looks something like this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Char** |  | **Overall** | **1** | **2** | **3** |
| **2** | A |  | 979 | 141 | 304 | 165 |
| **3** | B |  | 281 | 173 | 69 | 15 |

I would like to have this table dynamically update, so that when I filter the first sheet my table shows the frequency only for the strings that meet the filter.

In Excel, this can be accomplished using a combination of SUMPRODUCT and SUBTOTAL but this doesn't work in google sheets. I've seen this done in sheets using helper columns, but I would like the solution to work for a string of an arbitrary number of strings with different lengths without having to change the sheet. Can this be done in Google Sheets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hidden cells are assigned with the value `0`. One way to solve this is by adding a "helper" column in column `A` and set all the values in it to 1.

```
  |    A   |  B   | C |    D    |  E  |  F  |  G  
--+--------+------+---+---------+-----+-----+-----
1 | Helper | Char |   | Overall |  1  |  2  |  3  
--+--------+------+---+---------+-----+-----+-----
2 |    1   |  A   |   |   979   | 141 | 304 | 165 
3 |    1   |  B   |   |   281   | 173 |  69 |  15
```

Now instead of using `COUNTIF`, use the `COUNTIFS` formula where the second condition `A2:A = 1`. For example:

```
=COUNTIFS([YOUR_CONDITION], A2:A,"=1")
```

the `A` column values of hidden rows will calculate as `0`, therefore will not be counted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just so I'm clear though: If I have multiple countifs looking at multiple columns, will I need a helper column for each other column, or will simply having 1 helper column (ie 1 helper value per-row) be enough?

Comment: The helper column is just for hidden rows. It will make no sense to add more helper columns. The sole function of the helper column is to enable you to use a formula only on rows that are not hidden.